# get attribute option image from database magento

Tags: magento-1.9, database, custom-options

I want to display attribute option image on product detail page.

I have a variable that returns an array of option ID, but i  need the corresponding image to display the image:

```
<?php echo $_product->getProductTools(); ?>
```

I've tried this code but don t know how to replace 4550 by the result of the variable, and also the output should be an image(or list of image) not the url of image

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$sql        = "SELECT `image` FROM `eav_attribute_option` WHERE `option_id` = 4550";
$rows       = $connection->fetchAll($sql); //fetchRow($sql), fetchOne($sql),...
Zend_Debug::dump($rows);
```

Comment: what exactly $_product->getProductTools(); gives? if it gives array then why you have used echo?

Comment: yes that is an array

Comment: Could you help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

i ve tried this but it doesn t work: 
$producttools = $_product->getProductTools();

$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_rea‌​d'); $sql = "SELECT image FROM eav_attribute_option WHERE option_id IN $producttools"; $rows = $connection->fetchAll($sql); //fetchRow($sql), fetchOne($sql),... Zend_Debug::dump($row